# Can Jews Eat Hybrid Foods?

Tags: halacha, food, kilayim-forbidden-mixture

Are Jews allowed to eat crops and animals that have been hybridized? Whether crossbred themselves or by a non-native?

Answer (score 10):

One is allowed to eat kilayim produce, the only exception is kilayim produce that comes from the grapevine.

Refer to the Mishna in [Kilayim 8:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Kilayim.8?lang=bi)

> **כִּלְאֵי הַכֶּרֶם אֲסוּרִין מִלִּזְרֹעַ, וּמִלְּקַיֵּם, וַאֲסוּרִין בַּהֲנָאָה. כִּלְאֵי זְרָעִים, אֲסוּרִים מִלִּזְרֹעַ וּמִלְּקַיֵּם, וּמֻתָּרִין בַּאֲכִילָה**, וְכָל שֶׁכֵּן בַּהֲנָאָה. כִּלְאֵי בְגָדִים מֻתָּרִין בְּכָל דָּבָר, וְאֵינָן אֲסוּרִין אֶלָּא מִלִּלְבֹּשׁ. כִּלְאֵי בְהֵמָה מֻתָּרִים לְגַדֵּל וּלְקַיֵּם, וְאֵינָן אֲסוּרִים אֶלָּא מִלְּהַרְבִּיעַ. כִּלְאֵי בְהֵמָה אֲסוּרִים זֶה בָזֶה
>
> **Kilayim of the vineyard: it is forbidden both to sow and to allow to grow, and it is forbidden to derive benefit from them. Kilayim of seeds: it is forbidden both to sow and to allow to grow, but it is permitted to eat them, and all the more so to derive benefit from them**. Kilayim of clothing: is permitted in all respects, except that it is forbidden to wear them. Kilayim of beasts: it is permitted to raise and to keep, and it is only prohibited to cross-breed them. Kilayim of beasts: these one are prohibited with these.

Refer also to the Gemara in [Chullin 115a](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.115a.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) which states similarly.

Finally, see Rambam - [Mishneh Torah Hilchos Kilayim 1:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Diverse_Species.1.1?lang=bi):

> הַזּוֹרֵעַ זְרָעִים כִּלְאַיִם וְכֵן הַמַּרְכִּיב אִילָנוֹת כִּלְאַיִם אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהוּא לוֹקֶה **הֲרֵי אֵלּוּ מֻתָּרִין בַּאֲכִילָה** וַאֲפִלּוּ לָזֶה שֶׁעָבַר וּזְרָעָן שֶׁלֹּא נֶאֱסַר אֶלָּא זְרִיעָתָן בִּלְבַד. וּמֻתָּר לִטַּע יִחוּר מִן הָאִילָן שֶׁהֻרְכַּב כִּלְאַיִם וְלִזְרֹעַ מִזֶּרַע הַיָּרָק שֶׁנִּזְרַע כִּלְאַיִם

Although he is liable for lashes, when a person sows forbidden species together or grafts forbidden species of trees together, **the produce that grows is permitted to be eaten**, even by the person who transgressed and sowed it. For it is only sowing that is forbidden. It is permitted to plant a branch from the grafted tree or plant the seeds from a vegetable that was planted together with mixed species.

Comment: What about hybrid animals?